# UILabel is not giving text on logs when NSLog is applied on it.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel

My code is as follow and it is not working . If u found any mistake in it please tell me.

```
    name=@"Hello";
 label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 label.frame=CGRectMake(80, 23, 170, 20);
 label.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
 label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
 label.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];

 [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome, %@",name]];

  NSLog(@"label text in view did load method %@",label.text);
```

Comment: what does the console output say?

Comment: label text in view did load method null

Comment: Add **NSString *name = @"Hello"**;

Comment: @safecase had he not defined **name** there would have been an error thrown.

Comment: name is already NSString , and I have defined label in header file as UIlabel.

Comment: where is the define of "label"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to allocate UILabel first then it may work..

Add following line above the code

```
lable=[[UILabel alloc]init];
```

Comment: if he would have not allocated label,how come he get output

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are creating an instance of **label**:

```
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Even though you have defined **label** in your header does not mean you are initializing it. Use the above statement in before you set the properties of the label, then you will see the rsults you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    NSString  *name=@"Hello";
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    label.frame=CGRectMake(80, 23, 170, 20);
    label.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome, %@",name]];
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    NSLog(@"label text in view did load method %@",label.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```